# How to go live with PayPal Invoicing webhook?

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-webhooks, make.com

I'm very new to all of this and have been trying to teach myself as best I can.

I'm just trying to automate a simple process for my business; when a customer pays their PayPal Invoice, we send an email (in the billing info of that invoice) a link to the Dropbox folder associated with that Invoice No.

I've created a workflow in Integromat that works beautifully with the mock data from the webhook simulator.

However, I'm trying to go live and the webhooks just don't seem to be working? I've used Python to get tokens and to create the appropriate webhooks, and also tried it from the Developer Portal but when I go to the Live | Webhook Events section there's nothing there.

I feel like I'm missing something very simple!

N.B. I've pored over the API/Docs from PayPal but nothing is making anything clearer!

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What are some of the webhooks you created? Show us. Did you by chance create them in sandbox mode, for a sandbox account -- instead of your live account?

Comment: I created them for INVOICING.INVOICE.PAID and INVOICING.INVOICE.SCHEDULED -- and yes, it is definitely on my live account.

Comment: `import requests

url = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks"

payload = """{
  \"url\": \"https://hook.integromat.com/abc123\",
  \"event_types\": [
    {
      \"name\": \"INVOICING.INVOICE.PAID\"
    },
    {
      \"name\": \"INVOICING.INVOICE.SCHEDULED\"
    }
  ]
}"""
headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'authorization': "Bearer abc123",
    'content-type': "application/json"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)

print(response.text)`

Comment: Well that's not the response text

Comment: Apologies!! This is the response to a script for webhook details
`200
{"id":"ABC123","url":"https://hook.integromat.com/ABC123","event_types":[{"name":"INVOICING.INVOICE.PAID","description":"An invoice is paid, partially paid, or payment is made and is pending.","status":"ENABLED"},{"name":"INVOICING.INVOICE.SCHEDULED","description":"An invoice is scheduled.","status":"ENABLED"}]`

Comment: Okay, they do seem to be enabled there, wherever "there" is; still no identifying information. What needs to be confirmed is that you've done this on the correct live account, that you've paid an invoice on the correct live account, and that you are reviewing live events for the correct live account in developer.

Comment: Yeah so I've edited that data but the Webhook ID in the script that I've edited out is copied and pasted from the LIVE section in my Dashboard